# Pre-Calculating the material tiling on basis of geometry into three.js?

Tags: 3d, three.js

Want to place the texture onto geometry from GeoServer.
Geoserver want something like bounding box -(min,max) X1,Y1,X2,Y2 -  it can be geographic coordinates.

In Threejs I have PlaneGeometry, CanvasTexture for drawing images and after camera position or rotation change I want know points on geometry which are limits of rendered image.

Looking for extending something in Threejs. 
Work in progress is here: http://robertwpl.esy.es/tiled/terrain.html